# How do I get phpunit to work in cloud9 IDE?

Tags: laravel, phpunit, laravel-5.1, cloud9-ide

Just started out a laravel project on cloud9 IDE but I can't get phpunit to work. Every time I run the PHPUnit command I get a

> command not found

response. From the file structure in the project I can see phpunit files. I have never used cloud 9 for a laravel project before so I can't really tell if thats how it's supposed to behave. Has anyone successfully used phpunit on cloud9 before?

Comment: Have you installed phpunit globally on c9?

Comment: Yeah, later on I installed phpunit but then am getting "This version of PHPUnit requires PHP 5.6; using the latest version of PHP is highly recommended.
"...is there a way to upgrade my version of php without affecting my app?

Comment: If you are concerned about affecting your app, it would  be a better idea to install an earlier version of phpunit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can install phpunit globally using composer (available in the default C9 workspace). Phpunit 4.8.* works with PHP 5.5.

```
sudo composer global require phpunit/phpunit:4.8.*
```

The phpunit executable will be installed in `~/.composer/vendor/bin/` so add the following line at the end of the `~/.profile` file to make the command available elsewhere.

```
export PATH=~/.composer/vendor/bin:$PATH
```

Run `source ~/.profile` afterwards to register the new path then simply run `phpunit` in your Laravel installation folder.

Comment: Laravel makes it sound like they somehow install this by default...but yeah apparently you need to do this...